# fetch record count such as count the no of records before 12 weeks from current date and count the no of records after 12 weeks from current date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to retrive data from table with count such as before current year and after cuurent year.

My table is Patient having patientRegDate column such as

```
P_RegDate

2013-10-22

2013-10-24
2013-05-01

2013-10-28
2013-10-28
2013-10-28
2014-06-06
2013-10-29
2014-10-29
2014-10-30
2013-10-30
2015-10-30
2013-10-30
```

from this column i want to fetch record count such as **count the no of records before 12 weeks from current date** and also **count the no of records after 12 weeks from current date**. Lest say **current date is todays date**. How can I get the count of records before and after 12 weeks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, but you might have to fine tune the `where`clause to fit your needs:

```
SELECT Count12Before, Count12After 
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(P_RegDate) AS Count12Before 
    FROM table1
    WHERE p_regdate < DATEADD('ww', -12, DATE())
    ) before12,
    (SELECT COUNT(P_RegDate) AS Count12After 
    FROM table1
    WHERE p_regdate > DATEADD('ww', 12, DATE())
    ) after12
```

Answer (score 0):

select P_RegDate
from sample_table
group by P_RegDate
having datediff(parameters) >= 12

for e.g

SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2008-06-05','2008-08-05') AS DiffDate
out put : 61